# Why dcast gives strange result ? (Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length')

Tags: r, data.table

When I try convert a long data.table to wide, I have an unexpected result - see below:

```
               Cause Period      RESULT
              <char>  <ord>      <char>
  1: Total, all c...      1 154.4 (0.3)
  2: Total, all c...      1 154.4 (0.3)
  3: Total, all c...      1 154.4 (0.3)
  4: Total, all c...      1 154.4 (0.3)
  5: Total, all c...      1 154.4 (0.3)
 ---                                   
428: Information ...      4  34.8 (1.8)
429: Information ...      4  34.8 (1.8)
430: Information ...      4  34.8 (1.8)
431: Information ...      4  34.8 (1.8)
432: Information ...      4  34.8 (1.8)
> DT %>% dcast(Cause ~ Period)
Using 'Mean (skew)' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
             Cause     1     2     3     4
            <char> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1: Accidents (u...    12    12    12    12
2: COVID-19 [U0...    12    12    12    12
3: Diseases of ...    12    12    12    12
4: Ill-defined ...    12    12    12    12
5: Influenza an...    12    12    12    12
6: Information ...    12    12    12    12
7: Intentional ...    12    12    12    12
8: Malignant ne...    12    12    12    12
9: Total, all c...    12    12    12    12
```

Instead of showing me the strings (like `154.4 (0.3)`), it shows me the length of string (12).

What am I doing wrong?

What `fun.aggregate` should I use so it shows me the string instead of its length?

Comment: Your input data has multiple rows, and so multiple values of `RESULT`, for each (Cause, Period) combination. To specify how to convert that vector of multiple `RESULT` values into a single value to go in each "cell" (column element) of the output, provide a function in the `fun.aggregate` argument, and that function will be applied. It defaults to `length`. If all the values are the same, you could use `first` (or dedupe the data before `dcast`)

Comment: You have the same period for the same cause. ie one cannot tell whether the second  row is a new observation or just a duplicate. You either change the period or just list the values. try `fun.aggregate = toString`

Comment: Anyway what expected output do you want?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan was right - I had duplicates. Once I deduplicated, it worked. Thanks everyone! It was also great to learn about "first" an "toSting" options for `fun.aggregate`